# Anyone encounter SlowDown: Reduce your request rate response when uploading file large file > 1GB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, hapi.js

When I try to upload a file > 700-800 MB facing this error
(node:10892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SlowDown: Reduce your request rate. I have configured my server to accept file larger than 1 GB

```js
    await server.route({
      method: "POST",
      path: "/api/v1/uploads",
      config: {
        payload: {
          output: 'file',
          parse: true,
          maxBytes: 2000000000,
        },
      },
      handler: controller.create,
    });

  const create = async (response, h) => {
    try {
      ...
         const data = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filePath, (err, file_buffer) => {
        
        if (err) throw err;

        const params = {
          Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
          Key: key,
          Body: file_buffer,
          ACL: "public-read",
        };

        s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve(key);
        });
      });
    });
    ....
    } catch (exp) {
      ....
    }

  }
```

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory.

Comment: It seems possible you are hitting AWS S3 with too high a rate of requests.Maybe you should try doing `console.error(err)` on the `err` object from the  `s3.putObject()` callback.